# Add annotated value in json response (django rest)?

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I got a model that looks like this:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    author = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    chapters = models.IntegerField()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

and a "grand child" linked together through a `Chapter` model:

```
class Verse(models.Model):
    chapter = models.ForeignKey(Chapter, on_delete=CASCADE)
    verse = models.TextField()
    verse_number = models.IntegerField()
```

I wish to get the count of all verses that belongs to a book, and I'm fetching them like this:

```
Book.objects.annotate(Count('chapters', distinct=True), total_num_verses=Count('chapter__verse', distinct=True))
```

However, I'm not sure how to get this into my serializer. I was thinking of using a `SerializerMethodField` The goal is  to get the `total_num_verses` as a key/value pair in my json response

```
class BookSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    total_verse_count = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = "__all__"

    # this doesn't work..
    def get_total_verse_count(self, obj):
        print(obj.get_verses)
        return self.annotate(Count('chapters', distinct=True), total_num_verses=Count('chapter__verse', distinct=True))
```

I just get `'BookSerializer' object has no attribute 'annotate'`

Should I make a `@property` method in the Book model class itself?

`views.py` is just a plain `APIView`

```
class BookAPIView(APIView):
    """
    List all books
    """

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        books = Book.objects.all()
        serializer = BookSerializer(books, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An effective way to do that is adding a `readonly=True` field in the serializer:

```
class BookSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    total_verse_count = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = ['author', 'chapters', 'name', 'total_verse_count']
```

In the view, you then pass the annotated queryset to the serializer:

```
class BookAPIView(APIView):

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        books = Book.objects.annotate(
            total_verse_count=Count('chapter__verse')
        )
        serializer = BookSerializer(books, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: Nevermind - had a typo - seems to work fine. Is this an efficient way of doing it? Having the logic in the APIView instead of on the model / serializer itself?

Comment: @erikvm: yes, the serializer does not construct the queryset itself. If you would use a `SerializerMethodField`, then it could end up in an *n+1 problem*.

Comment: @erikvm: using `.annotate(Count('chapters'))` is also not necessary: this is here a simple `IntegerField` in the model.

Comment: I need to traverse down to verse I assume? `Chapter` has a ForeignKey to `Book` and `Verse` has a ForeignKey to `Chapter` - there is no real connection between book and verse. How does Django know about their relation

Comment: @erikvm: ah yes, then it is `Count('chapter__verse')`. I assumed that the `Verse` had a `ForeignKey` to `Book`.